# React Native SliderIOS not rendering properly

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native (done a couple example apps but I'm trying to branch out without a road map), and I'm having trouble with SliderIOS. My slider code is the following

```
<SliderIOS style={styles.slider} 
    onValueChange={(value) =>this.setState({value:value})} 
    maximumValue={100.0} 
    minimumValue={0.0} />
```

Styles includes:

```
slider:{
    height:30,
    margin:15,
  }
```

The getInitialStateMethod sets this.state.value to 0.

The track is missing and the nob is totally nonfunctional (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfqgc.png - can't post images yet).
I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, but not sure how to solve it. Let me know if you need more information to make my question sensible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that you did not specify a width for the slider. Try adding `flex: 1` to the style `slider`, which will make the slider consume all remaining space not required by other components. For further details see [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as well as the [React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html). Alternatively, you can set the `width` attribute. Below you can see some code I use for creating the slider illustrated by the following Image:

[image: Slider]

```
sliderConfigurationView:
{
    height: 20,
    flex: 1,
    margin: 6
}
```